# Safari browser window re-sizing tools?

Tags: testing, ipad, safari, responsive-design

There used to be free tools online such as 'Safari Resizer' and 'ipad peak'. Why are they all gone?

Are there anymore free online tools or safari extensions where you can easily resize the browser window to various resolutions for iPad testings? Or Safari dev tools that could do so?

Chrome you can easily do this in dev console, so what gives with Safari seemingly not allowing this anywhere anymore?

---

*Edit: Safari Develop > 'Responsive design mode' isn't a raw window resizer. For instance, when I compare a window with a specific browser size side by side to responsive design mode and with the window resolutions consoled onto the screen, in Safari's 'responsive design mode' they differ (proven also via actual iPad). So, this does not appear to be accurate nor what I'm looking for.*